# Using TeamViewer to login into only one user account

Tags: teamviewer

I am trying to use TeamViewer to remotely control only one user account, in my case `Remote User`, and the other one, named `Victor` to remain operable as usual, so that the one using `Victor` won't even know that I am remotely controlling an account.

Is this possible? If it is, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Which Operating System is running on this computer? As far as i know, it's only possible with Windows Server editions.

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1

Comment: You do understand that when you connect, Temviewer will notify the logged in user, that you have done so right?.  Why do you want to hide the fact your connected to the client?

Comment: Any answer acceptable, or further questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible with TeamViewer. TeamViewer will show the current screen that also the user will see in front of the pc.
What you want is a terminal server, which is only available for the server editions of windows.

Comment: is this possible with other software available on the market?

Comment: What do you want to do? Run fancy windows apps? Or just access files?

Comment: run windows apps and see the screen. I am not interested in hiding the remote control, but not influencing the other user working on the computer I want to control

Comment: What's the reason for not running them on your own pc? Performance? Printer connected? Licensing?

Comment: I am going somewhere and I cannot take my computer since it is a desktop, and I want to present some applications that cannot run on the computer there

Comment: It will not be fun, it will be slow, except it only shows some windows. What's your upload speed at home?
Can you use virtualisation on your portable device?
Can the user on the pc not just go to another pc?
I think there's no relation to the effort taken here.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have the same requirement (but using Windows 7) and I have solved it.  You need to use RDP (built into all Windows) instead of Teamviewer.  As @davidbaumann said, TeamViewer won't let you do what you want to do.  However, you can do this without the server edition - it does involve modifying Windows (specifically termserv.dll) which has implications for your licence, but the solution works great.

See here for Win 8 instructions:
http://rumyittips.com/how-to-enable-concurrent-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows-8/

I have run similar hacks in previous versions of Windows for years with great success.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to accomplish this because Teamviewer only allows you to view/control the active user desktop. You cannot control a user account "behind the scenes"